# How to get list of timezones in iOS like we get on the time of registration of web apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, timezone

How to get list of timezones in iOS, like we get on the time of registration of web apps, like shown in this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0qc5.png)?

Comment: Refer it **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to write

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);
```

and you will get all the TimeZone name and abbreviation of name.

Comment: Thanks iPatel, but i want in the format which is there in that link (GMT+04:30 Kabul). not like "Africa/Abidjan",

Comment: You will have to use the formatting styles (using NSDateFormatter)

Comment: This is now `knownTimeZoneIdentifiers`.